# Find the least number of Dragons required

Tags: graph-theory

The following graph represents the positions at Castle Dragonstone. Each edge indicates that the positions are within sight of each other.
This is not transitive; i.e., you can't see all the way along a row or column;
you can see only the adjacent positions.

[image: Dragonstone castle grid]

King Aerion is putting dragons in his castle. He has a condition that every position in the above graph has to be either occupied by a dragon or within the sight of a dragon. Find the smallest number of dragons that he would need in order to meet this condition.

Comment: Is it right to say that the goal is essential to partition the graph in subgraphs with a maximum diameter of 2 in such a way that you have the least amount of subgraphs?

Comment: What do you mean it won't work?

Comment: each such a subgraph has a single dragon on it then

Comment: A 3x3 grid doesn't have diameter 2. it actually has diameter 4. to get from the topleft position to the bottomright requires 4 steps. A position with a dragon on it with all positions in its sight are allways graphs of diameter 2

Comment: Where did the picture go? Without a picture or description of the graph the question is no longer clear at all.

Comment: I notice that the question was edited (in a way that makes it incomprehensible and makes nonsense of the answers) after what looks like a good answer was given. I notice that the user who posted the question also, at about the same time, posted a(nother) question from an ongoing competition. Is it too cynical to suspect that they posted their question, got an answer, and then tried to cover their tracks lest the competition organizers discover that they cheated?

Comment: (The other question was deleted on account of being part of an ongoing competition, which is why you won't find it from the user's user-page.)

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. I have posted the question again. I am extremely sorry for that.

Comment: Vertex Cover? :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The smallest number of dragons needed is:

> 40

This problem boils down into finding:

> The minimum vertex cover of the 13 x 13 grid-graph.  Another term for minimum vertex cover is ["Dominating Set"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominating_set).  The domination number for a 13 x 13 grid graph is 40.  Here is an example covering.
>   [image]
>  See [OEIS article for the domination number](http://oeis.org/A104519)

Comment: Damn...  thought I'd got this one... +1

Comment: @BrentHackers Your answer was great, except math. :)

Comment: Harsh...  I'm Maths-phobic...

Answer (score 4):

My answer:

> [image]
>  43 dragons (the number 2's in diagram).  The general pattern is optimal as its a tesselated cross shape (see right), resulting in 20% of squares with dragons in an infinite grid. It's optimal because every square is either a dragon or is only adjacent to one dragon. Then it's a matter of choosing a 13x13 sub-grid in this infinite tesselated grid such that the number of additional edge dragons needed (the red 2's in diagram) is minimised. Wherever you place the 13x13 subgrid, you can't get less than 9 of these, and there will always be 34 tesselated dragons.

Answer (score 4):

I got

> 41

by starting at the centre and working out...

> [image]

but I could have that wrong...

Here's a slightly better formatted picture:

> [image: ![enter image description here]